# 50-default.conf entry meaning

Tags: ubuntu, logging, rsyslog

I went through the rsyslog.d/50-default.conf file..
the entries in the files are like this.

```
auth,authpriv.*              /var/log/auth.log
*.*;auth,authpriv.none      -/var/log/syslog
#cron.*                      /var/log/cron.log
#daemon.*                   -/var/log/daemon.log
kern.*                      -/var/log/kern.log
#lpr.*                      -/var/log/lpr.log
mail.*                      -/var/log/mail.log
#user.*                     -/var/log/user.log
```

In some entries the log directory path is prefixed with hyphen sign(-).
can anyone please tell me what does it means..

Answer (score 3):

Adding the hypen (minus sign, "-") stops the log from being written to the file immediately.  Having the hyphen means you may lose some information that has not been written in the case of a crash, but not having it may have performance issues especially if you run programs that use logging in a very verbose manner.